# Generating an object (with recursion) where the other objects are not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, recursion

I have a game where I am generating a number of objects on the start of each level. I have one "finish hole" and some other large circular "trap" holes that appear in the level as well. Using recursion, I have tried to randomly generate my finish hole in a location where there are no other holes. I am trying to use OverlapSphere to find the objects in the area. If there is a hole in the randomised location, it re-runs the method to assign a random location. I don't want the finish hole to overlap because then it may be impossible for the player to reach the finish hole.

I've tried to redo my code, adjust the OverlapSphere arguments to make the checking zone larger or smaller, but that doesn't seem to fix it. In fact, when I change it to be too precise, it becomes stuck due to its recursive nature and causes a crash.

Below is my code when is called in the Start method of my Level Generator script.

```
void Start()
    {
        GenerateLevel();
    }

private void RandomiseFinishHolePos()
    {
        float _randomRangeX = Random.Range(-.75f, 4.75f);
        float _randomRangeZ = Random.Range(2f, 9f);
        FinishHolePosition = new Vector3(_randomRangeX, 0.1f, _randomRangeZ);
        holeColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(FinishHolePosition, 2f, 1 << 11);

        if (holeColliders.Length != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Collider found: " + holeColliders[0].name);
            RandomiseFinishHolePos();
        }
    }

    private void CreateFinishHole()
    {
        RandomiseFinishHolePos();
        if (FinishHoleActive == null)
        {
            FinishHoleActive = Instantiate(FinishHole, FinishHolePosition, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("Finish hole is NULL. " + FinishHolePosition);
            FinishHoleSpawn = FinishHoleActive.GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
        }
        else
        {
            FinishHoleActive.transform.position = FinishHolePosition;
            Debug.Log("Finish hole is NOT null. " + FinishHolePosition);
            FinishHoleSpawn.Play();
        }
```

Sometimes when it runs the method it it detects overlap between the positions, then places the finish hole in a new random place that is free of objects. However, it still fails very frequently which makes the level impossible to finish as the finish hole will be on top of another object.

Hoping there way be another way to acheive this goal, as perhaps this method is limited by OverlapSphere and recursion. Thanks for reading.

Comment: There's no reason to use recursion here. A `do...while` loop is sufficient and means you aren't cluttering the stack with return pointers. I also don't see why you bother distinguishing between a null `FinishHoleActive` and a not-null one. You do the same thing (besides the log message) both times.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit brutal, but you gotta try it:

```
private void RandomiseFinishHolePos()
    {
        float _randomRangeX = Random.Range(-.75f, 4.75f);
        float _randomRangeZ = Random.Range(2f, 9f);
        FinishHolePosition = new Vector3(_randomRangeX, 0.1f, _randomRangeZ);

        Physics.OverlapSphere(FinishHolePosition, 2f, 1 << 11); //ADD THIS LINE

        holeColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(FinishHolePosition, 2f, 1 << 11);

        if (holeColliders.Length != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Collider found: " + holeColliders[0].name);
            RandomiseFinishHolePos();
        }
    }
```

... or use something to slow down the overlap checking process

Comment: Yeah, no. Making the physics engine perform the check twice, discarding the first attempt, is not going to solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion here is dangerous, because it can quickly lead to a stack overflow. You could continue to call the same method until you find a spot, but there is a high likelihood that you will repeat the same values with more concentrated levels, and could find yourself wasting a lot of time. My recommendation is to randomize the first position you try to place the hole, and then "walk out" from that position until you find one that matches. This prevents you from repeating the same checks, but still allows for a fully randomized hole placement. A good algorithm to use as a reference is the [FloodFill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). I would recommend the alternative implementation involving queues, and specifying a specific distance between your checks.

I would also recommend moving your min/max ranges to some variables so that it's more easily configured, or so that you can pass them as a parameter. The Bounds class is perfect for this.

Example code:

```
private void RandomiseFinishHolePos()
    {
        bool holePlaced = false;
        Bounds holeBounds = new Bounds(
            new Vector3(2f, 0.1f, 5.5f), //Center
            new Vector3(5.5f, 0f, 7f) //Size
        );
        Vector3 startingPos = new Vector2(
            Random.Range(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.x),
            Random.Range(bounds.min.y, bounds.max.y), //Will always be 0.1f because the bounds has a center of 0.1f and a size of 0f.
            Random.Range(bounds.min.z, bounds.max.z)
        );

        Queue<Vector3> offsetQueue = new Queue<Vector3>();
        offsetQueue.Enqueue(Vector3.zero);
        while(!holePlaced || offsetQueue.Count > 0)
        {
             Vector3 offset = offsetQueue.Dequeue();
             FinishHolePosition = startingPos + offset;
             //Check to make sure the hole is within our bounds, otherwise skip over it.
             if(!holeBounds.Contains(FinishHolePosition)
             {
                 Continue;
             }

             holeColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(FinishHolePosition, 2f, 1 << 11);
             if(holeColliders.Length == 0)
             {
                 //Place your hole, there were no overlaps
                 //...Your code here
                 //Allow the while loop to finish
                 holePlaced = true;
             } else
             {
                 //try up, right, down, and left
                 Vector3 upOffset = offset + new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.1f);
                 Vector3 rightOffset = offset + new Vector3(0.1f, 0f, 0f);
                 Vector3 downOffset = offset + new Vector3(0f, 0f, -0.1f);
                 Vector3 leftOffset = offset + new Vector3(-0.1f, 0f, 0f);
                 offsetQueue.Enqueue(upOffset);
                 offsetQueue.Enqueue(rightOffse);
                 offsetQueue.Enqueue(downOffset);
                 offsetQueue.Enqueue(leftOffset);
             }
        }
    }
```

You can specify how close together you want your checks to be by changing the size of the up/right/down/let offset vectors. Even with the queueing, if you never find a position for the hole, the loop will end when it can no longer find any points within the bounds, resulting in no finish hole. If this happens, I would recommend regenerating the level entirely.